# appending a line to a file if absent

Tags: text-processing, grep, make, echo

I'd like to add a series of commands to a Makefile that append config lines *when they are not already present.* I've done this in the past in a manner like so:

```
grep -vq "keyword" /a/b/c.conf && echo "abc keyword" >> /a/b/c.conf
```

But, I'm clearly overlooking something. The command as-is causes the config line to be duplicated when re-run.

A manual test shows the pattern works as expected:

```
grep -vq "keyword" /a/b/c.conf && echo "the line is absent"
```

... prints *the line is absent* **only** when the line is actually absent. And, the `echo` command is correctly *not* executed when the line is *present.*

***What am I missing?***

---

<sup>**Note:** The examples above are condensed for readability. In reality, there will be many similar commands. Here's the particular command I've tried:</sup>

<sup>*grep -vq "md_module" /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf && echo "LoadModule md_module modules/mod_md.so" >> /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf*</sup>

Comment: I answered an almost identical question on the vi/Vim stack exchange: [How to append some line at the end of the file only if it's not there yet?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6248/4676)  My answer is scripted (non-interactive) and only uses POSIX features.  But, it only addresses the case where the line must be at the *end.*  For the case where it's allowed to be anywhere in the file, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6269/4676

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `grep -v` will match *lines* that do not match the expression, not files that do not match it...

So if your file has *any* lines that do not match it, `grep -v` will match those lines and so grep will return successful.

A better approach is to use a *positive* match for the keyword and then use `||` (instead of `&&`) to append the line if needed:

```
grep -q "keyword" /a/b/c.conf || echo "abc keyword" >> /a/b/c.conf
```

You probably got your test with `echo "the line is absent"` to say it was absent when it was indeed absent... And maybe to do nothing if that was the *only* line. If you test this further, I think you'll see that as long as it does have any lines that do not match keyword, you'll get a match.

I hope this clarifies it!

Comment: Wow. *Thank-you!* ... I think I need to step away from the keyboard for the night. I'm apparently failing to recognize the basics here ... thanks again!

Comment: @svidgen No worries, glad to help. It took me a while to actually "see" it as well... Shell can be tricky! :-)